# Error when appending data to existing data frame to retrain a model

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

I am adding more data to a my X_train data as well as to my y_train data in order to retrain my model with more data. I do this using pd. concat(). However, when I train my model using the concatenated dataset I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:1692: 
FutureWarning: Feature names only support names that are all strings. Got feature 
names with dtypes: ['int', 'str']. An error will be raised in 1.2.
  FutureWarning,
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-166-a11464987b97> in <module>
----> 1 model1_pool_preds = model1(LinearSVC(class_weight='balanced', 
random_state=42), OneVsRestClassifier, X_train_init_new, y_train_init_new, 
X_test_init, y_test_init, X_pool)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array__(self, 
dtype)
   1991 
   1992     def __array__(self, dtype: NpDtype | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 1993         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
   1994 
   1995     def __array_wrap__(

 ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I suppose this is happening because the data I added to the existing dataframe contains some strings instead of float numbers. How can I convert the entire dataset into float? my code is below:

```
y_train_init_new = pd.concat([y_train_init, X_pool_labeled.iloc[:, -7:]])
X_train_init_new = pd.concat([X_train_init, X_pool_labeled.iloc[:, 0:27446]])

def model1(model, classifier, X, y, X_test, y_test, X_pool):
  m = model
  clf = classifier(m)
  clf.fit(X,y)
  clf_predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
  C_report = classification_report(y_test, clf_predictions, zero_division=0)
  print(C_report)

  clf_roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, clf_predictions, multi_class='ovr')
  print('AUC: ', clf_roc_auc)
  clf_predictions_pool = clf.predict(X_pool)
  return clf_predictions_pool

model1_pool_preds = model1(LinearSVC(class_weight='balanced', random_state=42), 
OneVsRestClassifier, X_train_init, y_train_init, X_test_init, y_test_init, X_pool)
```

How can I convert all the data of the concatenated dataset into float data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a data frame that is entirely strings but can be turned without errors into numbers, you can just call `df.astype(float)` on the whole lot.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([str(i) for i in range(0, 1000)], columns=['x'])
>>> df
       x
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
..   ...
995  995
996  996
997  997
998  998
999  999

[1000 rows x 1 columns]

>>> df.astype(float)
         x
0      0.0
1      1.0
2      2.0
3      3.0
4      4.0
..     ...
995  995.0
996  996.0
997  997.0
998  998.0
999  999.0

[1000 rows x 1 columns]
```

This is more difficult if you have mixed non-numeric columns. Given that such columns can't be used anyway, just drop them and call `astype(float)` on the remainder.

Comment: This did not work in my case. I created a dataframe with 7 columns and the rows of this columns contain empty strings. Through a user interface, an user enter 1.0 to a row of a certain column based on a condition. The remaining rows I add zeros. When I concatenate this data frame with the previous dataframe I get the above error even if I convert the newly concatenated dataframe into a numpy array. I can't figure out what is wrong with the code

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your error

Comment: I have detected where the error was. It was not related to the float number, but with another variable that I was using within the function containing strings.